# What is the best way to send data to AsyncTasks

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

When i use AsyncTask i often use constructor to send parameter to it. But i also know that we can send parameters directly to AsynkTask like:

**Calling:** `new MyAsync().execute(stringUrl);`

**Defination:** `public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {...`

but i use:

**Calling:** `new MyAsync(stringUrl).execute();`

**Defination:** `public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
MyAsync(String url){.... }`

I want to know is there any difference between these two on behalf of performance or standard coding and which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

SO the differences will be while creating the constructor you your object will contain the data from the time that AsyncTask object is created. But when you pass the data through the AsyncTask queue.

So when you have to pass many parameters and dynamic then use Constructor but when the list is very short and parameter list is of same type a then you can pass it in your execute method. This maintains the readability of the code.

**Avoid**
Specializing your AsyncTask with Object Class and then typecasting it again from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, there is not much different in the two techniques the way you are using them here with a single String paramter.

The difference between using the constructor and using the execute method to pass a parameter is the fact that execute can take multiple objects of the type you define in your AsyncTask generic param type.  So you if you have this:

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

You can then call it like this:

```
new MyAsync().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Each of these individual parameters is available to you in the varargs type parameter of doInBackground.  The three dots after the param type means it's a Java [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) which accepts as many instances of that type, or even zero.  So learn about that if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Use class parameters for values you always need in the AsyncTask, like a username and password for a REST API call. This also allows reuse of the AsyncTask's execute method without specifying the arguments again.

The execute parameters must all be the same type. If you need different types, use class parameters.

Performance-wise, there is no difference (if there were, it isn't noticeable) you're just passing around variables.